# how to use $key in angular2 using material tables

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I cannot use the attribute $key in my angular 2 material table. is there any way to allow this to happen, as it throws an error assuming it has an issue with the '$'

```
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <a  [(ngModel)]="dataTag" [routerLink]="'../areas/' + row.id" ngDefaultControl> {{row.$key}}</a></mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

Comment: why don't you simple use row.key to access the data?Is there something specific that you are trying to do by using $?

Comment: it is how the data is held within the object.

Comment: what happens if you use row.key to access data?